# Proving even-ness in Agda

Tags: agda

I've been just getting started with Agda. I tried to prove, as exercise, evenness.

```
even : ℕ → Bool
even 0             = true
even 1             = false
even (suc (suc x)) = even x

x : even 12 ≡ true
x = refl
```

But asserting truth using `_≡_` seems like a really bad way. What would be the best way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is define an *inductive predicate* describing what it means for a number to be even. You could for instance write:

```
data isEven : ℕ → Set where
  ZisEven  : isEven 0
  SSisEven : {n : ℕ} → isEven n → isEven (2 + n)
```

You can then prove that your `even` function is sound: whenever it returns `true` (which is what `Data.Bool`'s `T` means) then the input was indeed an even number.

```
even-sound : (n : ℕ) → T (even n) → isEven n
even-sound zero          prf = ZisEven
even-sound (suc zero)    ()
even-sound (suc (suc n)) prf = SSisEven (even-sound n prf)
```

Now, you can write the following test rather than your previous equality: `even-sound` generates the proof that `isEven 12`.

```
y : isEven 12
y = even-sound 12 _
```

If you want to be even more precise in the way you specify `even`, you can also prove that it is complete: whenever an input is even, it indeed returns `true`.

```
even-complete : (n : ℕ) → isEven n → T (even n)
even-complete 0             ZisEven        = _
even-complete (suc (suc n)) (SSisEven prf) = even-complete n prf
```

Now, the specification of `Even`-ness I have chosen is a bit arbitrary, you may want to prove that it is equivalent to other formulations.

First, we can describe evenness in terms of oddness and reciprocally using mutually defined predicates:

```
mutual

  data isOdd′ : ℕ → Set where
    OisOdd′    : isOdd′ 1
    SEvenIsOdd : {n : ℕ} → isEven′ n → isOdd′ (suc n)

  data isEven′ : ℕ → Set where
    ZisEven′   : isEven′ 0
    SOddIsEven : {n : ℕ} → isOdd′ n → isEven′ (suc n)
```

Or we can use divisibility by `2` as the fundamental notion:

```
open import Data.Nat.Divisibility
isEven′′ : (n : ℕ) → Set
isEven′′ n = 2 ∣ n
```

Edit: I have included the proofs that these definitions are equivalent [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/b4cabb5f7f6c0bb4b66f) in case you want to peek.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer! A quick question I have: what is insufficient about using the ```isEven``` type as my proposition? It is inhabited only if its argument is an even number so why do I have to prove that it's sound? My understanding is that's to make sure that it is consistent with my definition of even-ness as I've expressed in ```even : ℕ → Bool```, is that correct?

Comment: I was trying to prove that the function `even` is sound and complete in terms of the specification `isEven`. The specification is indeed the thing you would take as being an obviously valid definition of evenness.